# how to make a regex to detect unicode characters?

Tags: asp.net, regex, unicode, character-encoding

I am working on a application in which i have to detect unicode characters for example my text is

```
Suzana R°u˘zi˘ckova and Viktor Kalabis, Yvonne Sebastaková, Linda Servitová,
Sandra Stevenson.
```

I have written a regex for it "[^\u0000-\u0080]+" but it not detects all characters.
 Also the word R°u˘zi˘ckova is not displaying correctly in c# because the combinning characters are on the top of alphabets not as a separate character.

How to make a regex which detects all combined characters and i am working in c#.

Comment: *Which* characters would you like to detect? And “R°u˘zi˘ckova” is not a word, it is apparently the name “Růžičkova” written in a special Asciification—does your data contain such strings, and how should they be handled.

Comment: yes my data contains such words and the characters in these words are ignored as a white spaces when fonts are applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

`'[\x00-\x7f]'` is ascii range

`'[^\x00-\x7f]'` is non-ascii char range

no idea about the re engine of asp.net, but you can give it a try.

here is a test with my `grep`:

```
kent$ (US-2998|✔) echo "Suzana R°u˘zi˘ckova and Viktor Kalabis, Yvonne Sebastaková, Linda Servitová,
Sandra Stevenson."|grep -oP '[^\x00-\x7f]'
°
˘
˘
á
á
```